# Not able to setup juggernaut push notification server on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I am developing a ruby on rails application to implement chat. I am not able to setup juggernaut server in production mode.

I followed [this guide](http://www.denofubiquity.com/nosql/412/) to setup redis. and its working perfectly fine.

Then I followed [this for setting up juggernaut](https://gist.github.com/1055322). But when I am trying to start juggernaut its not working.

Here is the out for grep commands to check that redis is working but juggernaut is not.

[image]

When I am trying to stop/start redis server its gives me output ie:

```
 Starting/Stopping redis-server: redis-server.
```

But nothing when i m doing the same for juggernaut. Check screenshot.

[image]

Some other things to check what actually going on:

1. Executable file permissions to /etc/init.d/juggernaut file -- YES

   ```
       -rwxr-xr-x 1 fizzy fizzy 1310 Sep 19 11:06 juggernaut
   ```
2. PIDFILE=/var/run/juggernaut.pid' is defined. Does that exist? --- NO
3. In the 'start' part it runs 'chown juggernaut:juggernaut'. Does the user juggernaut exist and is it member of the group juggernaut?  -- YES/YES

   ```
     cat /etc/group
         redis:x:1002:
         juggernaut:x:113:

     groups juggernaut
         juggernaut : juggernaut
   ```
4. Running sudo juggernaut start the server, but i want to it to keep on running in background process/service.

[image]

I am stuck now. Can anybody help me.

**EDIT**

```
     fizzy@li136-198:~$ sudo ls -l /usr/bin/juggernaut 
              ls: cannot access /usr/bin/juggernaut: No such file or directory
     fizzy@li136-198:~$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin/juggernaut 
            lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Sep 20 02:48 /usr/local/bin/juggernaut -> ../lib/node_modules/juggernaut/server.js
```

I tried changing

```
        DAEMON=/usr/bin/juggernaut
```

to

```
        DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/juggernaut
```

after that i tried restarting the juggernaut using

```
         sudo /etc/init.d/juggernaut start
```

Server started but not as background process/service.

**PS: Somebody please create proper tags for this question.**

Comment: Is the /etc/inin.d/juggernaut file the one they provided from the crib sheet you are using? Can you provide the output of ls -l /usr/bin/juggernaut ( I'm trying to see if its executable )? Line 21 of https://gist.github.com/1055322#file_juggernaut2_for_init.d_startup.sh checks to see if its executable and it isn't printing out that its starting up the service.

Comment: @ChristopherEvans check my edit..

Answer (score 0):

The `juggernaut` program doesn't seem to daemonise itself by default, and the initscript doesn't provide parameters to make it do so. Check the output of `jaggernaut --help` for options regarding daemon mode, and if you find them modify the initscript to provide those. For example:

```
OPTIONS="--daemonize"
...
if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid juggernaut:juggernaut --exec $DAEMON -- $OPTIONS
```

If there aren't any options you'll have to make `start-stop-daemon` do the daemonising (which isn't ideal for various reasons). To do this add the `--background` and probably `--make-pidfile` options:

```
if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid juggernaut:juggernaut --background --make-pidfile --exec $DAEMON
```